# Como enviar peticion AJAX con headers

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

explico mi inconveniente: Estoy tratando de consumir una [API](https://developer.mercedes-benz.com/apis/image_api/docs) de una pagina entonces realizo la siguiente petición:

```
    <script>
    var button = document.getElementById("btn_submit");
    button.addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault;
        var vin = document.getElementById("id_vin").value;
        console.log(vin);

        var url = `https://api.mercedes-benz.com/image/v1/vehicles/${vin}/components?apikey=mi_clave`;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            accepts: "application/json",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (result) {
                // process result
                $('#result').html(result.ip);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                 // log error in browser
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
    }) 
</script>
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Por lo que leo falta como agregarle la cabecera o algo así es mi primera vez trabajando con AJAX así que me pueden guiar se los agradecería muchísimo.

Saludos :D

**ACTUALIZACION.**

```
            var url = `https://api.mercedes-benz.com/image/v1/vehicles/${vin}/components?apikey=xxxx`;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            accept: "application/json",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (result) {
                // process result
                $('#result').html(result.ip);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                 // log error in browser
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
    })
```

Asi me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si le doy clic al link puedo ver el resultado entonces no se como tratar ese resultado para que lo imprima en la pagina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACION 2**

al modificar el dataType: "json"

me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACION 3**
Envio mi peticion como 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y he aca la respuesta de la pestaña Network>Hearders
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el preview de la respuesta (lo que quiero) 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la respuesta en json me parece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaro que mi pagina la tengo en local es decir no la he subido a ningun servidor , la estoy corriendo desde mi laptop local

Comment: saludos podrias hacerlo algo asi: headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }

Comment: o tambn:  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("custom_header", "value");
  },

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿estas corriendo la aplicación de API en la misma IP (De la web) pero distinto puerto? (Por ejemplo tu aplicación web esta corriendo en el 192.168.0.1:8000 y tu API en el 192.168.0.1:8001?

Comment: mi web desde mi pc por ahora pero la otra api no es mia esta en otro dominio

Answer (score 2):

Habria que ver dos cosas:

1. debes solicitar una autorizacion como un token, cuando ya lo tienes envias tus token obtenido en las cabecera de la peticion.
2. habria que ver si la API te permite enviar las credenciales en tus cabeceras en ese caso ya no tienes que enviar un token sino el usuario que te han asigando

```
var button = document.getElementById("btn_submit");
button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault;
    var vin = document.getElementById("id_vin").value;
    console.log(vin);

    var url = `https://api.mercedes-benz.com/image/v1/vehicles/${vin}/components?apikey=mi_clave`;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        headers: {
        'Authorization':'token'
        type: 'GET',
        accepts: "application/json",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (result) {
            // process result
            $('#result').html(result);
        },
        error: function (e) {
             // log error in browser
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: segun la documentacion solo debo enviar la api key
https://api.mercedes-benz.com/image/v1/vehicles?apikey=<insert_your_api_key_here>

https://developer.mercedes-benz.com/apis/image_api/docs

Comment: @Naoto pero si ves la key va en la URL entonces solo debes concatenar lo que debes quitar es la comilla ´ por una comilla simple: 'https://api.mercedes-benz.com/image/v1/vehicles/${vin}/components?apikey='+mi_clave

Comment: que error estas obteniendo?

Comment: El siguiente:

Refused to execute script from 'https://api.mercedes-benz.com/image/v1/vehicles/WDC0G0FB2JF356639/components?apikey=xxxx&callback=jQuery33107497260740562925_1538414513472&_=1538414513473' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Actualizare mi estado para que veas lo que me sale

Comment: dataType:'json'

Comment: ahora me sale el error de origen cruzado, lo pondre en la actualizacion de la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes es un error de CORS (control de acceso HTTP), porque estás haciendo la petición desde un dominio diferente al que aloja las imágenes. Lo que tienes que hacer es pedir a los que mantienen la API que agreguen tu dominio a la lista de acceso. Como estás trabajando desde un entorno local, eso puede ser más complicado. Ten en cuenta que acceder al punto terminal (endpoint) directamente con el browser no supone un problema de CORS, sino solamente cuando la petición se realiza a través de AJAX, por eso puedes acceder a la URL del endpoint con el navegador, sin problemas.

El control CSRF con token, compo sugieren otros usuarios, se hace solamente para peticiones idempotentes o POST, no para GET.

Comment: Y como hacen los demas para solicitar informacion de una api externa? no creo que siempre uno le tenga que pedir a los creadores de esas api que agreguen mi domio o si ? :O

Comment: Si la API es para uso anónimo (no autenticado), el encabezado Access-Control-Allow-Origin
 de respuesta debe ser '*'. Pero seguramente, ese no es el caso en la API con la que trabajas. De modo que o autenticas con una cookie de sesión, por ejemplo, o con otro método acordado. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: para usarla segun la documentacion solo necesito la api_key que se la envio y ya

Comment: ok, ten cuidado porque has publicado tu API key en un comentario, deberías editarla. He ido a la documentación a ver y pienso que pueden pasar dos cosas. Tu servidor local no está corriendo en protocolo https. Tu API key está equivocada. Intenta hacer la misma petición desde postman a ver qué resultado obtienes. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: Uy muchas gracias no me habia fijado jeje estoy añadiendo esa extension a ver y te digo :D gracias

Comment: Puse mi url, type: no auth, tipo: get con mi key y el codigo del vehiculo , en header no agregue nada y me dio respuesta en json

Comment: no se creo que es el servidor de aca mande la peticion como sale en postman descargando el codigo ajax y quitandole los headers y me sale error >:C intente ponerle en header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", lo intente sin eso, con el token de postman, sin ese token de postman mmmm ya no se que intentar

Comment: y en tu local, la url desde la que se envía la petición, es http o https?

Comment: segun el header dice Request URL: https://api.mercedes-benz.com/image/v1/vehicles/WDC0G0FB2JF356639/components?apikey

Comment: Esa es la url a la que haces la petición. Pero tu problema me parece a mi tiene que ver con de dónde sale tu petición. me llama mucho la atención ese X:/Escritorio bla bla bla %API. Etc. Tienes que irte a la pestaña "Network" de developer tools y hacer un screenshot de la pestaña "Response" de la llamada OPTIONS y GET. Porque si no va a estar muy difícil ayudarte. Y también pon lo que dice la URL en tu navegador donde tienes levantado tu servidor local y desde donde haces la llamada a la API

Comment: vale dejame y actualizo la pregunta con lo que me pides :D porque si me trae el resultado pero no lo puedo como procesar por el error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." es que esta en local la pagina X:Escritorio es donde tengo los archivos xD

Comment: lo que tienes que poner de la respuesta es un pantallazo de headers. en local también puedes correr un servidor. precisamente un servidor local. dependiendo de tu setup, de los lenguajes que uses, etc, cómo lo montas o el tipo de servidor que necesitarás. A esta altura, creo que ese es tu problema. Por ejemplo, si fuese una aplicación node.js, podrías usar Express. Tendrías que hacer esa pregunta aparte, para poder respondertela, y tendrías que dar bastante información acerca de tu entorno (local), como hardware, software, lenguajes que usas en el backend, frontend, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega a tu peticion el tipo de dato 'jsonp'

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

tu peticion quedaria de esta manera:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        accepts: "application/json",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (result) {
            // process result
            $('#result').html(result.ip);
        },
        error: function (e) {
             // log error in browser
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
```